# JavaScript: How to convert an HTML string into a JavaScript number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number that I need to pull from my html:

```
<span>123,456.78</span>
```

How can I convert this string into a number that I can do math on?

```
var numberString = $('span').text();
var realNumber = Number(numberString); //returns NaN
```

A jQuery-only solution would be okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what `realNumber` does, but here's how I'd convert that string into a number:

```
var numberString = $('span').text();
var amount = + numberString.replace(/,/g, '');
```

This removes the commas, then uses the [`+` unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) to convert the string to a number.  In your example, the result is the number `123456.78`.

Comment: Good catch on the comma (although I'd still use parseFloat); upvoting yours too. Still deleting mine.

Comment: @Dave I prefer to use the unary operator because it returns `NaN` when it fails, rather than an incorrect number.

Comment: Oops! I just realized my code sample was wrong. I was trying to assign the number to a variable called "realNumber", not call a function.

Comment: Nice! - "unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number"

Answer (score 7):

parseInt() or parseFloat() would just about do it.

```
var number = parseFloat($('span').text());
```

after checking and seeing this doesn't work...

try

> <strike>var number =
>   $('span').text().replace(/([^0-9\.])/g,"");</strike>

```
var number = parseFloat($('span').text().replace(/([^0-9\\.])/g,""));
```

Comment: `parseFloat("123,456.78")` returns `123`. That doesn't seem like a useful result to me.

Comment: this update will replace all none number and '.' characters. including '$' ',' and '¢'

Comment: @lonesomeday, yes.. i tested it after i posted it. see update.

Comment: @rlemon. You'd still need to call parseFloat in the second method to convert to a number

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

```
var numberString = $('span').text();

var number = Number(numberString.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```